# Fix: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 37 Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I'm using MS SQL server.

I have used **pivot** in my query. What I've done yet is given below:

### SQL Procedure

```
--/*==========================================================
--
--
--
--===========================================================*/

--CREATE VIEW View_BASequenceExportDtl
--AS

--ALTER PROCEDURE Proc_BASequenceExportDtl 

--AS

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX)


SET @cols = ISNULL(@cols + ', ', '') (
                                            SELECT Table3.vAnalyteName
                                            FROM Table3,BaSequenceScheduleHdr,BAAnalyteSampleHdr
                                            WHERE Table3.nTable2No = BaSequenceScheduleHdr.nTable2No
                                                  AND Table3.cStatusIndi <> 'D'
                                     )

SET @stmt = 'SELECT     
            Table1.nBaSequenceScheduleHdrNo,
            Table1.vSampleId,
            Table1.vSampleName,
            Table1.iSeqNo,
            Table1.vSampleType,
            Table2.vInjectionVolume,
            Table3.vAnalyteName,
            Table4.nConcentration,
            Table1.cStatusIndi

        FROM Table1

                INNER JOIN BaSequenceScheduleHdr
                      ON(BaSequenceScheduleHdr.nBaSequenceScheduleHdrNo =  Table1.nBaSequenceScheduleHdrNo
                         AND BaSequenceScheduleHdr.cStatusIndi <> ''D'')

                INNER JOIN Table2
                      ON(Table2.nTable2No = BaSequenceScheduleHdr.nTable2No
                         AND Table2.cStatusIndi <> ''D'')

                INNER JOIN Table3
                      ON(Table3.nTable2No = BaSequenceScheduleHdr.nTable2No
                         AND Table3.cStatusIndi <> ''D'')          

                LEFT JOIN BAAnalyteSampleHdr
                     ON(BAAnalyteSampleHdr.nTable2No = BaSequenceScheduleHdr.nTable2No
                        AND BAAnalyteSampleHdr.nTable3No = Table3.nTable3No
                        AND BAAnalyteSampleHdr.cStatusIndi <> ''D'')          

                LEFT JOIN Table4
                     ON(Table4.nBAAnalyteSampleHdrNo = BAAnalyteSampleHdr.nBAAnalyteSampleHdrNo
                        AND Table4.vSampleID =  Table1.vSampleId
                        AND Table4.cStatusIndi <> ''D'')

        PIVOT (
                SUM(Table4.nConcentration) FOR Table3.vAnalyteName IN ( ' + @cols + ' )
              ) AS PVT'

exec(@stmt)
```

### Reason For Using Pivot in Procedure

Here `concentration` is dependent on `Analyte`. So what I want is that that depending on dynamic `Analyte` name its `concentration` should be under that column.

### How it should be work

In here, first `@cols` will contain all the `analyte` names which will passed to the **`PIVOT`**. And the final **`exec(@stmt)`** should return the all data as a **`View`**

---

But I'm getting the error: **`(10 row(s) affected) Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 37 Incorrect syntax near ')'.`**

And also, I'm using **pivot** first time. So Please let me know if any error in it also.

Comment: You're getting a syntax error, plain and simple. This should not be too hard to fix... Pivot has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Tomalak : I know it is for syntax, but still, I'm unable to find out the one. As per the error instruction, there is no error on that particular line as per my opinion. That's why I've put this question finally on here.

Answer (score 0):

This part is not making sense

```
SET @cols = ISNULL(@cols + ', ', '') (
                                            SELECT Table3.vAnalyteName
                                            FROM Table3,BaSequenceScheduleHdr,BAAnalyteSampleHdr
                                            WHERE Table3.nTable2No = BaSequenceScheduleHdr.nTable2No
                                                  AND Table3.cStatusIndi <> 'D'
                                     )
```

Comment: It is for getting all values of `Analyte`. Because I can not write it into `Pivot`'s `IN`.

Answer (score 0):

The way you build up the comma-separated list of columns needs to be change. Change that to:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

SELECT @cols = @cols + N', ' + Table3.vAnalyteName
FROM Table3,BaSequenceScheduleHdr,BAAnalyteSampleHdr
WHERE Table3.nTable2No = BaSequenceScheduleHdr.nTable2No
AND Table3.cStatusIndi <> 'D'

set @cols = stuff(@cols, 1, 2, N'')
```

Comment: B I N G O ! ! !

Thank you mate.

But one more problem is there, I don't know that how to get data from this procedure e.g. we do it using view.

Comment: @user3085495 It would be better to ask a separate question for that. On Stack Overflow you raise only one problem per question.

Comment: Your change in this `@cols` did removed my error but its not giving me any output. Why?

Comment: @user3085495 I can't tell you that as I don't have access to the data and I won't be able to check the logic of your query. Try to print the value of `@stmt` and analyse that query bit by bit.