# Multi-part Identifier : Error while using PIVOT in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I want to use `PIVOT` in a stored procedure to get the rows. What I've performed is:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = ''

SELECT @cols = @cols + Table3.vAnalyteName+ ','
                                        FROM Table3,Table5,Table6
                                        WHERE Table3.nBAChildProjectsNo = Table5.nBaSequenceScheduleHdrNo
                                              AND Table3.cStatusIndi <> 'D'

SET @cols = substring(@cols, 1, len(RTRIM(@cols)) -1 ) 

--SET @cols = stuff(@cols, 1, 2, '')

SET @stmt = 'SELECT
            Table1.nBaSequenceScheduleHdrNo,
            Table1.vSampleId,
            Table1.vSampleName,
            Table1.iSeqNo,
            Table1.vSampleType,
            Table2.vInjectionVolume,
            Table3.vAnalyteName,
            Table4.nConcentration,
            Table1.cStatusIndi

        FROM Table1

                INNER JOIN Table5
                      ON(Table5.nBaSequenceScheduleHdrNo =  Table1.nBaSequenceScheduleHdrNo
                         AND Table5.cStatusIndi <> ''D'')

                INNER JOIN Table2
                      ON(Table2.nBAchildProjectsNo = Table5.nBAchildProjectsNo
                         AND Table2.cStatusIndi <> ''D'')

                INNER JOIN Table3
                      ON(Table3.nBAchildProjectsNo = Table5.nBAchildProjectsNo
                         AND Table3.cStatusIndi <> ''D'')

                LEFT JOIN Table6
                     ON(Table6.nBAchildProjectsNo = Table5.nBAchildProjectsNo
                        AND Table6.nBAProjectAnalyteDtlNo = Table3.nBAProjectAnalyteDtlNo
                        AND Table6.cStatusIndi <> ''D'')

                LEFT JOIN Table4
                     ON(Table4.nBAAnalyteSampleHdrNo = Table6.nBAAnalyteSampleHdrNo
                        AND Table4.vSampleID =  Table1.vSampleId
                        AND Table4.cStatusIndi <> ''D'')

        PIVOT (
                SUM(Table4.nConcentration) FOR Table3.vAnalyteName IN ( ' + @cols + ' )
              ) AS PVT'
exec(@stmt)
```

But I'm getting the error of **`Multipart Identifier`** as below:

> Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
>   The column 'nBaSequenceScheduleHdrNo' was specified multiple times for 'PVT'.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The multi-part identifier "Table1.nBaSequenceScheduleHdrNo" could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The multi-part identifier "Table1.vSampleId" could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The multi-part identifier "Table1.vSampleName" could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   The multi-part identifier "Table1.iSeqNo" could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   The multi-part identifier "Table1.vSampleType" could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   The multi-part identifier "Table2.vInjectionVolume" could not be bound.
>   ......

I'm using PIVOT for the first time. So please bare with it. And let me know if I can handle this error with solution.

What I want to do here is, to get all the columns in `SELECT` with `Analyte` column of PIVOT. And `Pivot` should be performed on basis of `Analyte` and `concentration` columns.

Values of `Analyte` column needed in header and its concentraion should be filled up as row.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fix: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 37 Incorrect syntax near ')'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349706/fix-msg-102-level-15-state-1-line-37-incorrect-syntax-near)

Comment: It was mine post only. But it was for the `@cols`. I've solved that problem. Now it is for the other issue.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is too late to reply, just for future reference for others..

First of all, after applying PIVOT, all columns of the pivoted set must be referenced using the alias specified for the PIVOT clause. As per the manual:

> When a derived table, rowset or table-valued function, or operator
>   clause (such as PIVOT or UNPIVOT) is used, the required table_alias at
>   the end of the clause is the associated table name for all columns,
>   including grouping columns, returned.

If you Alias all columns in the `SELECT` list with `PVT` will be fine or you can even remove alias for all columns will also be fine.